# How can I determine which AGP Graphics cards or whether an AGP graphics card, is compatible with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, agp

How can I determine which AGP Graphics cards or whether an AGP graphics card, is compatible with Windows 10?

A friend's computer has an AGP graphics card that is not compatible with windows 10, i'd like to change it for another AGP graphics card, which he can get off ebay second hand(obviously since AGP is old). But i'd want the "new" AGP graphics card he gets to be compatible. How can I ensure that it will be compatible with Win10?

Comment: Determine if the card has Windows 10 drivers, if it does not, then it won't be compatible

Comment: If you are getting an older model video card even brand new ones can be pretty cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft's page [Windows 10 - Specifications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/windows-10-specifications):

> **Graphics card:**  DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver

So you need a video card that supports DirectX9 or better, and that supplies a driver that implements the [Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570593(v=vs.85).aspx) v1 or later.

Determining if a WDDM driver is available will most likely require researching each potential product's support/driver download pages (if they still exist)  to determine.

WDDM v1 was introduced with Windows Vista, so finding cards that advertised Vista-specific support may be an angle to approach finding them.